# Extend borders on header divs

Tags: css, html

Can any of you kind souls please tell me how I can extend the border or div of my headers to full width of page? Like I have on my footer. Here's my project http://2facced.com/marc-ecko/ Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to modify the width of these header elements from pixel values to 100% - either inline like you are doing right now or in the CSS file. You will also need to move them outside of `#page-wrap` since this has a fixed width of 992 pixels.

```
#header1 div{
width:100%;
}

#header2 div{
width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to place it outside of your page wrapper. Simply move it outside of the page wrapper and it automatically turned into 100% width when I edited it using Google's Inspect element. IF you want to keep the stuff above your header, then you have to do something else. I would advise that you wrap the first part (before your header) into a page wrapper. Leave the header outside of the page wrapper and then start another page wrapper after your header.

Comment: thank you so much for your help tiffany. People are ganging up on me and I'm fairly new to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to see the container of your header to get the full width of the page. If the width of the container of the header has some fixed width then you can not go beyond that width until you position your header absolute even if you set the width of the header to 100%. So check your container for the header to obtain full width.